# Python: Arcpy: Adding data to a shapefile

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-desktop

Complete arcpy beginner here...

I have a shapefile with the fields `CNTRY_NAME` and `GDP_HEAD`.

I have a list in Python `gdppop2002 = [['Country1, 234.1232341], [Country2, 23.2341234],...etc...]`

I'm trying to write each float value in the list to the corresponding country row in the shapefile's attribute table. I need to check if each Country in `gdppop2002` matches a `CNTRY_NAME`, and then write the float value in the list to `GDP_HEAP`. From a couple of hours of googling this appears to require creating an insert cursor, but I'm a little lost. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: The online help contains code examples http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html  You will need to AddField, then use an update cursor.  Peruse the documentation for details.

Comment: gdppop2002 looks more suited to be stored as a dictionary than a list of short lists so could be worth considering if refactoring your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid most of the redundant conditional logic of Jason Miller's answer by converting your list into a dictionary:

```
gdppop2002_dict = {}
for pair in gdppop2002:
    gdppop2002_dict[pair[0]] = pair[1]
```

You can then iterate through the rows and update values directly from the dictionary:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ['CNTRY_NAME', 'GDP_HEAP']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        country = row[0]
        if country in gdppop2002_dict:
            row[1] = gdppop2002_dict[country]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

(Note that I've used [`arcpy.da.UpdateCursor`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000014000000), which only became available in ArcGIS 10.1. If you're on 10.0 or older, you'll have to use [`arcpy.UpdateCursor`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000064000000), which is less efficient and has slightly different syntax.)

Comment: Good call on changing this to a dict... I realize that my code wasn't completely ideal, was just trying to "make it understandable..."

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import arcpy

gdppop2002 = [["Country1", 234.1232341], ["Country2", 23.2341234]]
fc = "c:/YourFolder/YourShapeName.shp"
field1 = "CNTRY_NAME"
field2 = "GDP_HEAD"

cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
row = cursor.next()
while row:
    countryName = row.getValue(field1)
    for subList in gdppop2002:
        if subList[0] == countryName:
            row.setValue(field2, subList[1])
            cursor.updateRow(row)
            break;

    row = cursor.next()
```